# How to bind data to a property in an ancestor element using XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I am writing a WPF application using C# and MVVM design pattern.

I have the following `c#` object

```
public class ProductStyleGenericModel : BindableBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? SelectedValue { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem<int>> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have the following view-model which is the `DataContext` of my view.

```
public class EditProductViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public IEnumerable<ProductStyleGenericModel> Styles { get; set;}
    // .......
    //  I removed the rest for the code of simplicity
}
```

Finally, I have the following XAML-view which simply displays a `ListBox`. Each `ListBoxItem` has a grid where a `TextBlock` is placed on the left and a `ComboBox` placed on the right.

```
<GroupBox Header="Product Description">
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Styles}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                                  Grid.Column="1"
                                  SelectedValue="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}, Path=SelectedValue, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                  SelectedValuePath="Value"
                                  DisplayMemberPath="Text"/>
                    </Grid>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</GroupBox>
```

When an item in the `ComboBox` is selected I want to update the DataContext.Styles.SelectedValue using Two-Way Binding so I know which value is selected then store it in the database.

**Problem**

For some reason, each `SelectedValue` in the `Styles` collection is always `0` and does not update when the selected item is selected.

I am guessing that the why I am trying to bind the `ComboBox.SelectedValue` to `Styles.SelectedValue` is incorrect.

The logic that I am trying to write here is... find the immediate ancestor with a type of `ListBox` then bind to the `SelectedValue` property on the source object using the `Path=SelectedValue`.

Please note that I am implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the `BindableBase` class using [Fody.PropertyChanged package](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) which injects the `RaisePropertyChanged` into property setters at compile time.

**Question**

What am I doing here, how can I fix this problem?

**UPDATED**

If needed, here is my `SelectedListItem` class

```
public class SelectListItem<T> : BindableBase
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public SelectListItem(T value, string text)
    {
        Value = value;
        Text = text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless BindableBase somehow breaks the rules of the Language, none of your properties have Change Notification set up. You have to actually raise the ChangeNotification events in each set accessor. Auto-implement properties will not do.

Comment: @Christopher `BindableBase` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and with the `Fody.PropertyChanged package` linked above, the property automaticly raise the property change. The package simple `injected the raise property change into property setters` at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the binding may be wrong. Try this instead:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
          Grid.Column="1"
          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue}"
          SelectedValuePath="Value"
          DisplayMemberPath="Text"/>
```

The property SelectedValue I think you want to bind to is in the current data context. The property you were binding to is the SelectedValue on the ListBox-control and that don't make any sense to me at least.